# Sorting results in sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sphinx

Is there an easy way to sort sphinx results?

Recently posted (by dates)
Highest paid (highest value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sphinx has **sorting-modes**: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes, what you need is **SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC mode** & **SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC mode**

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean beyond the order by clause?

```
select *
from mytable 
order by 1
```

Comment: Can you do that in Sphinx?!  That looks like a SQL query